# How to fix MEMORY LIMIT EXCEEDED in my Java code?

Tags: java

I'm trying to submit a problem in the platform lightoj.com.
Link of the problem: https://vjudge.net/problem/LightOJ-1088

I'm trying to submit my java solution for this problem.
Am I doing something wrong for which it is using much memory than expected?
I don't understand why it is giving Memory Limit Exceeded verdict.

Here goes my JAVA code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Main {

    static class FastReader { 
        BufferedReader br; 
        StringTokenizer st; 

        public FastReader() 
        { 
            br = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        } 

        String next() 
        { 
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) 
            { 
                try
                { 
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()); 
                } 
                catch (IOException  e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
            return st.nextToken(); 
        } 

        int nextInt() 
        { 
            return Integer.parseInt(next()); 
        } 

        long nextLong() 
        { 
            return Long.parseLong(next()); 
        } 

        double nextDouble() 
        { 
            return Double.parseDouble(next()); 
        } 

        String nextLine() 
        { 
            String str = ""; 
            try
            { 
                str = br.readLine(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
            return str; 
        } 
    }

    static int l,r,mid,i1,i2,now;

    static int get(int a, int b, int[] arr, int n) {
        if(arr[n-1]<a || arr[0]>b) return 0;
        l = 0;
        r = n-1;
        while(l<=r) {
            mid = (l+r)/2;
            if(arr[mid]==a) {
                now=mid;
                break;
            }
            if(arr[mid]<a) l = mid+1;
            else {
                r = mid-1;
                now = mid;
            }
        }
        i1 = now;
        l=0;
        r=n-1;
        while(l<=r) {
            mid = (l+r)/2;
            if(arr[mid]==b) {
                now = mid;
                break;
            }
            if(arr[mid]<b) {
                now = mid;
                l = mid + 1;
            } else {
                r = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        i2=now;
        return i2-i1+1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FastReader sc = new FastReader();
        OutputStream outputstream = System.out;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputstream);

        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int n,q;
        int a,b;
        int[] arr = new int[100000];
        long ans;
        int cas = 0;
        while(t--!=0) {
            out.println("Case " + ++cas + ":");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            q = sc.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            while(q--!=0) {
                a = sc.nextInt();
                b = sc.nextInt();
                ans = get(a,b,arr,n);
                out.println(ans);
            }
        }
        out.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you run this program locally?

Comment: pay attention to the memory limits specified in the problem. usually there is a time limit and performance limit.

Comment: Locally it runs perfectly because I don't use huge dataset like them. Memory limit given is 32 MB and the time limit is 2 seconds.

Comment: It could be that you are creating too much garbage. I suggest trying to create less objects.

Comment: I just have an object of an integer array of length 100000. Is that too much? Without PrintWriter, FastReader and this one, I didn't create any more object.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. For me using following procedure got accepted.

1. Allocate all the variables of the test case inside for or while loop
2. After printing data make those variables point to null
3. Call `System.gc();`
   This way redundant memory will get cleared by java garbage collector.

For your problem do something like this below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FastReader sc = new FastReader();
    OutputStream outputstream = System.out;
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputstream);

    int t = sc.nextInt();
    int n,q;
    int a,b;
    long ans;
    int cas = 0;
    while(t--!=0) {
            out.println("Case " + ++cas + ":");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            q = sc.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            while(q--!=0) {
                a = sc.nextInt();
                b = sc.nextInt();
                ans = get(a,b,arr,n);
                out.println(ans);
            }
            arr=null;
            System.gc();
        }
        out.close();
}
```